# Disallow "//" in a regular expression (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to disallow double forward slashes (//) in my regular expression (and thus allow single /), but my solutions doesn't work.

There also has to be NO / at the beginning and ending of a string (this work!):

```
/^[^/][a-z0-9-/]+[^/]$$/
```

this allows for example example///example// but NOT/dzkoadokzd///zdkoazaz

Now I want to disallow multiple "/" after each other.
I've tried this but it doesn't work (I'm new to regular expressions):

```
/^[^/]([a-z0-9-]+[/]{1})+[^/]$$/
```

Comment: It is called a forward slash or just slash. Backslash is \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is a meta character in regex. You need to escape it with a backslash (`\/`)

```
/^[^\/]([a-z0-9-]+[\/]{1})+[^\/]$/
```

Comment: Thanks it's good to know!
But this regular expression doesn't work (so does mine): it's invalidate text(a-z). Did you know where the error is? Thanks

Comment: This regex doesn't work, because it expects a single character after last "/". To fix it, add a "+" before the "$".

Comment: There is another potential problem with this regex. I expained everything in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is a requirement, but the regex from jperovic, by using [^/] will accept any character, which is not a slash / (so it will also pass strings like "**@abcd/efgh/ijkl/#**" (notice the @ and #), but in other parts of the regex we try to limit the characters to [a-z0-9-]. If we want to restrict the character range for the complete string, check the regex below.

```
/^[a-z0-9\-](?:[a-z0-9\-]|\/(?!\/))+[a-z0-9\-]$/
```

Comment: Perfect, it was indeed a problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BTW, if you just want to test for slash at the start or end or double elsewhere:

```
function badSlash(s) {

  var re = /^\/|\/\/|\/$/;

  return re.test(s);
}
```

You can add another OR for whatever other patterns you don't want, e.g.

```
  var re = /^\/|\/\/|\/$|[^a-z0-9\/]/;
```